# preparing columns in descending order in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

```
                  EthylAcetate      PrintCylinder   HDpolythene
                       12                8               5
                        9                2               9
```

I wanted to add the values in each column separately and order the columns in a `datagrid` in the descending order according to the total.. above i have mentioned the code that i used.

It do give me the total of each row, but it doesn't give me the the columns sorted.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sum(eAce) as SumEacetate , sum(pCl) as PrintCylinder  , sum(hdp) as HDpolythene FROM TblSalesOrder ORDER BY SumEacetate, PrintCylinder  , HDpolythene DESC ;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write `DESC` keyword to each column

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sum(eAce) as SumEacetate , sum(pCl) as PrintCylinder  , sum(hdp) as HDpolythene FROM TblSalesOrder ORDER BY SumEacetate DESC, PrintCylinder DESC, HDpolythene DESC ;"
```